# How do i filter model instances respect to its virtual attribute in yii2 model using ActiveDataProvider?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have Product class and it contain two attribute 'price' and 'sale_price' and also i have a getter `getOriginalPrice`.

```
/**
 * This is the base model class for table "product".
 *
 * more attribute here..
 * @property float $price
 * @property float|null $sale_price
 * more attribute here...
 */
class Product extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * get product original price 
     * 
     * @return float
     */
    public function getOriginalPrice()
    {
        if(!is_null($this->sale_price) && (float)$this->sale_price > 0)
        {
            return $this->sale_price;
        }

        return $this->price; 
    }

}
```

so my question is that how can i filter the Product model respect to this virtual attribute `originalprice`?

i have tried to filter the model using `product/index?sort=originalprice` and `product/index?sort=-originalprice` in the url and put this code in `ProductSearch` model but no luck.

```
$query = Product::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query
        ]);
        
        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

      
        //filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'price' => $this->price,
            'originalprice' => $this->originalprice,
            'product_cat_id' => $this->product_cat_id,
        ]);


        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name]);

        return $dataProvider;
```

does anybody knows how to solve it?

Comment: You can't. ActiveDataProvider filters records at SQL query level, so your virtual attributes (defined at PHP level) are not available. You need to  build proper SQL condition using actual fields available in DB table.

Comment: As @rob006 said.  The SQL will look something like this  case when sale_price > 0 then sale_price else price end as original_price

Comment: thank your both for the comment and put me in the right direction. i got the point.